# CMAC for messages shorter than 128bit

Tags: cbc-mac, cmac

[RFC4493](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493) describes the generation of AES-CMAC and padding for messages with length > sizeof(aes128_key). However I need to generate the CMAC for a series of messages shorter than 16 byte.

So I'd like to ask if it is viable to:

- Pad M0 with 0 up to 16 bytes
- Pad M_last with the proposed padding (first bit 1, others 0)

As the message always will be M0 || M1 with a fixed size, is the subkey generation still required? Or can it be replaced by a fixed value?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES-CMAC is defined for messages of any length.

The algorithm can be reduced to the following, if you have non-empty messages smaller than the block size:

```
(K1,K2) := Generate_Subkey(K);
n := ceil(len/const_Bsize);
M_last := padding(M_n) XOR K2; 
X := const_Zero;
Y := M_last XOR X;
T := AES-128(K,Y);
return T;
```

You don't need to derive some non-standard way of padding your messages.

---

You should note that `len/const_Bsize` in the RFC is floating point division. The C implementation does this little trick to not use floating point division: `n = (length+15) / 16;`.

Shameless plug: I have a JavaScript implementation of AES-CMAC that you can play around in: [Online AES-CMAC calculator](http://artjomb.github.io/cryptojs-extension/)

Comment: Hi Artjom, basically this means there is no block chaining in the CMAC generation and only path b (message does not fit the block size). Too bad this exact case isn't explicitly described in the RFC, so thanks for your answer.